# "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" raised in near-vm folder during near-sdk-as yarn installment

Tags: yarnpkg, nearprotocol, near

When I tried to install near-sdk-as on my laptop (Intel-based macOS 10.13) with the command:

```shell
yarn add -D near-sdk-as
```

I got the following error:

```shell
❯ yarn add -D near-sdk-as
yarn add v1.22.17
info No lockfile found.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
warning near-sdk-as > near-sdk-core > near-vm > binary-install > axios@0.19.2: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning "near-sdk-as > near-sdk-core > @as-pect/cli@6.2.4" has incorrect peer dependency "assemblyscript@^0.19.3".
warning "near-sdk-as > near-sdk-core > @as-pect/cli > @as-pect/assembly@6.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "assemblyscript@^0.19.3".
warning "near-sdk-as > near-sdk-core > @as-pect/cli > @as-pect/core@6.2.1" has incorrect peer dependency "assemblyscript@^0.19.3".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
error /Users/admin/Develop/Learn-Near/NEAR-101/node_modules/near-vm: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node ./install.js
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/admin/Develop/Learn-Near/NEAR-101/node_modules/near-vm
Output:
/Users/admin/Develop/Learn-Near/NEAR-101/node_modules/follow-redirects/node_modules/debug/src/debug.js:47
    hash  = ((hash <
                    

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1032:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/Develop/Learn-Near/NEAR-101/node_modules/follow-redirects/node_modules/debug/src/node.js:14:28)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

Other info:
npm version: 8.3.1
yarn version: v1.22.17

Any thoughts on how to fix the error and complete the sdk installation?

Thanks!

Comment: Please specify node and npm, yarn version as well

Comment: npm version is: 8.3.1

yarn version is: v1.22.17

Comment: and what about node version?

Comment: node version: v16.14.0

Comment: I've just tested that and it on mac and it works, could you please remove node_modules and also rename yarn lock to yarn.lock.bak file and try again?

Comment: Hello sina.ce, thank you so much for your time. The node.js tag is suggested by StackOverflow. I've removed it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Is it solved?

Comment: I renamed yarn.lock to yarn.lock.bak, but still with no luck. The same error showed up.

Answer (score 2):

Try `yarn cache clean --force` first, then rerun `yarn`.

Why? You have broken dependency files cached, so you want to clean the cache and download from scratch